# how to iterate bash script to run command?

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to copy multiple folders in years wise from one s3 bucket to another

```
aws s3 sync s3://bucket_one/2022XX s3://bucket_two/2022XX (XX is 01 to 12)
```

I've folders under `bucket_one` like 202201,202202 so on and for other years too.

Can I create any shell script which runs for months of a years to copy data to `bucket_two` ?

I'm new in shell script, I know how run loops but place holders using not sure.

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with `for` loops and variable substitution aka parameter expansion. You can read more about it in the official manual [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) but personaly I find it easier to read something like [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-shell-parameter-substitution-2.html).

Anyway for your specific case you can try something like this:

```bash
for month in {01..12}; do
    aws s3 sync s3://bucket_one/2022$month s3://bucket_two/2022$month
done
```

To debug if something doesn't work you can `echo` the command out.
Ex:

```bash
for month in {01..12}; do
    echo "aws s3 sync s3://bucket_one/2022$month s3://bucket_two/2022$month"
done
```

Comment: will it hold while executing the current aws command until its completed  and before going for next iteration ?

Comment: Yes, but there are ways to make it async if it's needed. The easiest way to do it is by adding an `&` sign at the end of the command.